# SDL_PollEvent not triggering

Tags: c, sdl

I've only recently started working in C and using SDL, so I'm sure it's something basic that I mess up, but every example code I can find looks like mine, except mine doesn't work. So any help would be welcomed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
SDL_Event event;
int game_running = 1;
while (game_running)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type) /* checking for event type */
        {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_UP:
                        printf("You pressed up.\n");
                        break;
                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                        printf("You pressed down.\n");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                printf("You stopped pressing the button.\n");
                break;
            case SDL_QUIT:
                game_running=0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
SDL_Quit();
printf("The program stopped.");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What is/isn't happening when you compile and run your program (and what is your complete program, specifically)?

Comment: This is in the main() area, so right now that's all that should happen, when I noticed a KeyDown event I want to write "oh hey you pressed key up" (sorry I didn't write that part in english), and a different message for a KeyUP event.

And well not working simpy means the program never gets through PollEvent and into the switch.

Comment: I updated the post, with the whole code, as I said right now it doesn't do anything else besides this. I'm just trying to implement a simple keyevent check system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event handling is associated with a display surface. Add something like this:

```
SDL_Init (SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_SetVideoMode (320, 200, 8, 0);
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working now, I thought I could use it without creating a window, I'm not even sure what my thought process was. Anyway, thanks. :)